# Is it possible to run small test queries fast against Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

We are writing an application which allows users to run SQL queries against several different database backends including Apache Spark. We have a test suite that runs many small queries against these backends. These queries are significantly slower against Spark than against the other backends we support (up to 50x slower in some cases) and this is causing problems for our test suite.

I assume this is because Spark is designed as a distributed query engine, and the overheads this involves dominate when the queries themselves are very small.

As an example, here is a script which creates a table and repeatedly runs a trivial query against it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (v INT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
SELECT MAX(v) FROM test;
SELECT MAX(v) FROM test;
SELECT MAX(v) FROM test;
SELECT MAX(v) FROM test;
SELECT MAX(v) FROM test;
SELECT MAX(v) FROM test;
SELECT MAX(v) FROM test;
SELECT MAX(v) FROM test;
SELECT MAX(v) FROM test;
```

I can run this script against Spark using Docker:

```
docker run --rm -i apache/spark:3.3.1 /opt/spark/bin/spark-sql < spark-test.sql
```

Despite the tiny amount of data these queries never complete in less than about 250ms.

Is there any way of configuring Spark so as to reduce this overhead? I am not concerned with data integrity or persistence. We just need to be able to check that the queries execute as expected.

Answer (score 1):

### Spark config

Some of this is probably intractable overhead, but the following settings can help speed up small spark tests significantly.

```
"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" = "1"
```

The default shuffle partitions is 200, which creates a lot of tiny files in small tests, the effect compounds if lots of joins are done on small datasets.

```
"spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold" = "-1"
```

Since your data is small all joins can be broadcast (sent to all executors instead of shuffled).

See the [spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) for details of configuration options. You can set these via the cli with `--conf`, or using `.config()` on the SparkSession object when you create it.

### Other suggestions

The above settings may not help with the simple example you give. So let's dig into that a bit.

When you run these commands:

```
CREATE TABLE test (v INT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
```

Spark creates a folder `test` in `/opt/spark/work-dir/spark-warehouse/` and creates 5 files, 1 per insert. For the reasons given above small files are undesirable, so we can write a single file, using a hint.

```
INSERT INTO test SELECT /*+ COALESCE(1) */ * FROM VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
```

Another thing we can do is mount a memory based `tmpfs` to the locations spark writes to, which should be faster than disk.

```
docker run --rm --tmpfs /opt/spark/work-dir/ --tmpfs /tmp/ -i apache/spark:3.3.1 /opt/spark/bin/spark-sql < spark-test.sql
```

We can also try using csv instead of parquet, which is optimised for large columnar data `CREATE TABLE test (v INT) USING CSV;`. We can use also `CACHE TABLE test;` after the insert, again to keep the table in memory.

The improvement I saw was modest ~10% in the simple example, but it may help more on your suite overall.

Comment: Thanks very much for this @Kieran! Using those two settings seems to get us around a 20% overall speedup on a Spark tests which isn't to be sniffed at, although it still leaves those tests significantly slower than everything else.

On the tiny example I posted above they don't seem to make any difference. I guess those timings are dominated by fundamental overheads?

Comment: Added some more ideas for the simple case.